# Object is a field but used like a type?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to bind data to a form, but I keep getting the following error:

AbDesktop.FrmCreditCards.tmpData is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'.

this is the code causing the error, any and all help would be appreciated.

```
public partial class FrmCreditCards : Form
    {
        tmpCreditCardData tmpData = new tmpCreditCardData() { CreditCardName = "Reece" };
        private HotelConferenceEntities db = new HotelConferenceEntities();
        private tblCreditCard databaseAccessObject;
        private tmpData dataTransferObject;


        public void databinding()
        {
            // Create forward map using AutoMapper - from database to dataTransfer
            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<tblCreditCard, tmpData>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CreditCardName));

            // Create reverse map using AutoMapper - from dataTransfer to database
            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<tmpData, tblCreditCard>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.CreditCardName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));

        }
```

Comment: what is `tmpCreditCardData`?

Answer (score 2):

The generic parameters of CreateMap are the problem.
You have to use the type `tmpCreditCardData` instead of the variable name `tmpData` as the compilation error says.

```
        // Create forward map using AutoMapper - from database to dataTransfer
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<tblCreditCard, tmpCreditCardData>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CreditCardName));

        // Create reverse map using AutoMapper - from dataTransfer to database
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<tmpCreditCardData, tblCreditCard>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CreditCardName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same name for type and field - rename the field tmpData to something else - ie:

```
    tmpCreditCardData tmpData2 = new tmpCreditCardData
      { CreditCardName = "Reece" };
```

There were some comments about conventions - convention specifies classes should start with upper case letter and be named like

```
MyFavouriteClass
```

and fields should be named like

```
myFavouriteField
```

(it starts with lower case letter)

Someone also distinguish private fields with underscore

```
private MyFavouriteClass _myFavouriteField
```

If you stick with them you shouldn't run into this problem.

Comment: (Or even better, rename the types to start with an uppercase character to follow the default naming guidelines)

Comment: this is not ne problem. He uses a variable name as a generic parameter in the call to `CreateMap<T,U>()`.

Comment: @Zebi See the declarations of `tmpCreditCardData tmpData` and `private tmpData dataTransferObject`. Asumed tha the code compiles, `tmpData` is used as both a type and a variable name.

Comment: Ah ok I missed that one! Sorry!